# Transaction handling with spring data and JDBC Template

Tags: spring-data-jpa, jdbctemplate, spring-transactions

I would like to do a batch delete without first making a Select for each object. I didn't find a way with spring data jpa and the entity manager to do this.For this reason I try the JDBC template.
However, I get problems with the pageable.
This code workes fine and all deletes are executed by batching. Unfortunately with an unnecessary select for each entity.

```
@Transactional
public void deleteFoos() {

   Page<Foo> page = repository.findAll(PageRequest.of(0,50);
   Pageable pageable = null;
   do {
      if ( pageable != null ) {
         page = repository.findAll( pageable );
      }
      repository.deleteAll( page.getContent() );
   } while ( (pageable = page.nextPageable()) != Pageable.unpaged() );
}
```

What I have tried now is to implement the whole thing directly with the JDBC template.

```
@Transactional
    public void deleteFoos() {
    
       Page<Foo> page = repository.findAll(PageRequest.of(0,50);
       Pageable pageable = null;
       do {
          if ( pageable != null ) {
             page = repository.findAll( pageable );
          }
          //repository.deleteAll( page.getContent() );
 jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(
         "DELETE FROM foo WHERE (id = ?)",
         page.getContent(),
         page.getTotalItems(),
         ( preparedStatement, argument ) -> {
            preparedStatement.setObject( 1, argument.getId() );
         } );
       } while ( (pageable = page.nextPageable()) != Pageable.unpaged() );
    }
```

However, the third and fourth page is always empty. It seems the delete is executed directly. Auto commit is off, what else could be wrong?

EDIT: Solution from Jens works fine: "You can simply repeatedly request the first page and delete it."

Comment: 'It seems the delete is executed directly' - ummmmm... why wouldn't it be? You had me genuinely puzzled

Comment: Also, why do you feel you need paging to delete all content from a DB table? Just call `DELETE FROM foo` and be done with it

Comment: Well the delete query is limited to id's. This is also an example for demonstration, but describes the problem. Unfortunately it's not that easy

Comment: @K.Nicholas feel free to answer the open question. This would be a big help :)

Comment: It seems the delete is executed directly' - ummmmm... why wouldn't it be? You had me genuinely puzzled --> Because it should executed after the transaction when the method is end. If you delete entities during paging it cannot be work

Comment: 'It seems the delete is executed directly' - ummmmm... why wouldn't it be? You had me genuinely puzzled. Also, why do you feel you need paging to delete all content from a DB table? Just call DELETE FROM foo and be done with it.

Comment: There is no reference to spring-data-jdbc in the question. I removed the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `JdbcTemplate` does simply execute SQL statements, so yes, they get immediately executed. There is no caching involved, as with JPA operations.
But even JPA operations get flushed to the database before a query gets executed, so the difference isn't that big.

You can simply repeatedly request the first page and delete it.

But using pagination with deletes doesn't make much sense, you could just delete all rows from the table and be done with it in a single roundtrip to the database:

```
DELETE FROM foo
```

If you want to delete in batches you could still do this without loading anything in your application. The details might be database dependent, but something similar to this should work nicely:

```
DELETE FROM foo
LIMIT 100;
```

Comment: Thanks Jens for you answer.

The example just shows the problem in a simple way. In the application, a querydsl query is executed, which selects the IDs which shoul deleted. If the DELETE is always executed immediately, what happens with a rollback? Then only parts are rolled back because the previous ones are already being executed?

I have the same problem with an update, i.e. also here I have to go through the first page again and again?

Or do I have a chance to design the behavior as with JPA, so that all statements are executed at the end of the method / transaction?